# Biholomorphism between neighborhood of a complex submanifold and a neighborhood of zero section of its normal bundle

Tags: complex-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Let X be a compact Kähler manifold, $M\subseteq X$ be a complex submanifold, is there a biholomorphism between a neighborhood of the zero section of the normal bundle $NM$ of $M$ and a neighborhood $U(M)\subseteq X$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The existence of such a biholomorphism is rather rare. For example, as a simple exercise you can check that already for a conic in $\mathbb CP^2$ such a biholomorphism does not exist. At the same time, in the case $M$ is "exceptional" in $X$, for example, $X$ is obtained by a blow up from $X'$ at a point $x'\in X'$ and $M$ is the exceptional divisor, the situation is the often the one you want (I don't specify purposefully here what "exceptional" means).

*Solution to the exercise.* Everything follows from the fact that each holomorphic map from $\mathbb CP^1$ to itself has at least one fixed point. Indeed if a neighbourhood of a conic $C$ in $\mathbb CP^2$ were biholomorphic to a neighbourhood of $O(4)$ bundle over $\mathbb CP^1$ then the restriction of $T \mathbb CP^2$ to $C$ would holomorphically decompose as a sum $N_C\oplus TC$ where $N_C$ is a line subbundle of the restriction. Now consider a line $L_x$ through each point $x$ of  $C$ tangent to the direction $N_C(x)$. Finally consider $y(x)=L_x\cap C$ the second point of the intersection of $L(x)$ with $C$. We got the map $C\to C$ without fixed points, this is a contractioction.

**PS.**  I remember a theorem that states that the only smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb CP^n$ that has a neighbourhood isomorphic to a neighbourhood of a zero section in a line bundle is a linear $\mathbb CP^{n-1}$. Thanks to jvp for the link below!

Comment: Dmitri, you are probably thinking on Van de Ven Theorem. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61596/when-does-the-conormal-bundle-sequence-split/61609#61609

Comment: Dear jvp,thanks a lot: your link is very interesting. I can't access Van de Ven's article nor Ionescu/Repetto's right now: can you (or someone else) help?

Comment: Dear Dmitri, thank you for posting your solution to the exercise.However I don't understand how the existence of the biholomorphic map   gets you that family of lines in $\mathbb CP^2$ parametrized by the conic.

Comment: @Dmitri: First of all thank you for the answer. Let me see if i understand, Let X be a kahler manifold and M a submanifold, M could not have a neighborhood that retract holomorphically to it, but if i blow up X along M and call E the exceptional divisor, E has a neighborhood that retracts holomorphicaly to it because it has "enough" complex lines to retract?

Comment: Dear Georges, sorry I was too sloppy, hope now the "solution" reads well. Dear Italo, I have to apologize, I would not be able to state a correct general version of the theorem on exceptional divisors. I just have a collection of examples in my head when this works. I have to say, that I don't think, that if you take say a blow up of $\mathbb CP^3$ in a curve of high degree then the exceptional divisor will have a good neighbourhood. In fact, I think, it will not... On the other hand, if you blow up an isolated singularity, you have better chance (again I don't know a precise result..). 

Comment: Dear Dmitri, your solution is elegant and clear, thanks a lot. So the restriction of the tangent bundle  $T\mathbb CP^2$ to the conic $C$ is $\mathcal O_C(3)\oplus \mathcal O_C(3)$, right?

Comment: Yes Georges, this is correct, one can construct this splitting explicitly. Namely take two points on the conic -- $p$ and $q$ and for any point $x\in C$ chose two directions in $T_x\mathbb CP^2$: the directions of the lines $[xp]$ and $[xq]$.  It is easy to see that this defines two transversal line sub-bundles.

Comment: Dear Dmitri, this visual proof of the splitting is really heart-warming to a geometer. And the symmetry of your construction also shows that the two sub-bundles are isomorphic, hence isomorphic to $\mathcal O(3)$ since the degree of the restricted tangent bundle is $6$. Прекрасно,  поздравляю!

Comment: Dear Dmitri, how about the case when $X$ is a Calabi-Yau 3fold and $M\subset X$ is a $(-1,-1)$ curve? It seems that in this paper
arXiv:0809.4748, pag.4 the fact that $M$ has a neighborhood biholomorphic to the disc bundle inside $N_M$ is regarded as obvious, but after reading this discussion I am not quite sure why...

Comment: Dear YangMills, the case of $(-1,-1)$ curve is the "good" one indeed. But one needs some work to prove this. I just started to think how to do this. It is standard to say that if you blow down $(-1,-1)$ curve then you get an ordinary double point, i.e. singularity $(x_1^2+...+x_4^2)=0$. Of course, from this the existence of bundle follows. But how to prove that this is so? I never saw the proof, so I decided to go to http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/alg-geom/pdf/9602/9602006v1.pdf . There Miles Reid speaks (in chapter 4) about contracting curves on surfaces. For example a $\mathbb CP^1$ with normal  

Comment: bundle $O(-2)$ contracts to an ordinary double point. Miles Reid says that any analytic singularity can be characterised by $O_{X,P}/m_P^N$ for some large $N$.  Well... sorry... I see now that I can not give a convincing argument immediately, I'll think about your question. (anyway the answer will require some cohomology calculation...)

Comment: Dear Dmitri, thanks a lot for your answer, which was very helpful. I found an explanation for why $M$ can be contracted to an ordinary double point in the paper of Friedman "On threefolds with trivial canonical bundle": basically he blows up $X$ along $M$ and on the blowup the exceptional divisor is $P^1\times P^1$ with normal bundle $O(-1,-1)$ so this can be contracted to an ordinary double point, and the resulting variety is also the contraction of $M$ inside $X$.

Comment: Dear YangMills thanks for telling me about Friedman! Indeed this is the sure place to find the result (I completely forgot this reference :) 
)

Answer (score 7):

The answer is "no" because in general there does not even exist a neighbourhood $U$ of your submanifold that holomorphically retracts to the submanifold. In fact Finnur Lárusson has [proved](https://doi.org/10.1007/s002080050057) the following (warning: I have kept his notations, so as to faithfully quote him. In particular $[X]$ is $\mathcal O(X)$, the line bundle on $M$ associated to the divisor $X$)

> **Theorem.** Let $X$ be a connected hypersurface in a compact complex manifold $M$ of dimension at least $2$. If
>
> 1. $H^0 (M, TM) = 0$
> 2. $\dim H^0(M, [X]) \geq 2$, and
> 3. $H^1(M, [X]^{\vee} \otimes TM) = 0$,
>
> then no neighbourhood of $X$ retracts holomorphically onto $X$.

Note that the hypotheses are very easy to satisfy: (1) holds for $K3$ surfaces for example  and (2), (3) will follow from $X$ being sufficiently ample.

[Here](http://www.maths.adelaide.edu.au/finnur.larusson/papers/retr.pdf) is a freely downloadable version of Lárusson's   article, from his homepage.