# Extending a holomorphic vector bundle: a reference request

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

Let $Y$  be a complex manifold,   $X\subset Y$ a compact submanifold, and $E\to X$ a holomorphic vector bundle. Can $E$ be extended
to a  bundle over an open neighborhood of $X$ in  $Y$? (Four years ago  I have  asked   this  question on MO [Extending the tangent bundle of a submanifold](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249050/extending-the-tangent-bundle-of-a-submanifold)  for the  case  $E=T_X$.)

After  tinkering  with this problem  for  a while   I   found  a necessary condition, there is an invariant in $H^2(X, \mathcal{N}_{X/Y}^*\otimes End(E))$ which  must be zero for an extension to be possible. So far, so good.
Now I  think  about writing it down and submitting somewhere (assuming it is a new result). But, in a decent  paper  there are supposed to be references to known  results in the same direction, right?  And this is what the real problem is:  damned if I have a clue where to look! It is all miles away from  areas  I am familiar with (mostly  differential geometry), and this far I could not find anything remotely relevant. So, it would be nice if someone  helps me with this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems to me that your result follows by Proposition 1.1 of the paper

P. A. Griffiths: [**The extension problem in complex analysis. II: Embeddings with positive normal bundle**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2373200), Am. J. Math. **88**, 366-446 (1966). [ZBL0147.07502](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0147.07502),

that can be freely downloaded [here](https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/extensionproblemcomplexanalysisII.pdf). The statement is the following:

> **Proposition 1.1 (Griffiths 1966).** If $\alpha$ is a holomorphic vector bundle $\mathbf{E} \to X$, then $$\omega(\alpha_{\mu-1}) \in H^2(X,\,\Omega(\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbf{E}, \, \mathbf{E})(\mu))).$$

Here $\omega(\alpha_{\mu-1})$ is the obstruction to extending $\mathbf{E}$ to the $\mu$th infinitesimal neighborhood $X_{\mu}$ of $X$ in $Y$, provided that you already have an extension $\alpha_{\mu-1}$ to $X_{\mu-1}$, and  $$H^2(X,\,\Omega(\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbf{E}, \, \mathbf{E})(\mu))= H^2(X, \mathrm{End}(\mathbf{E}) \otimes \mathrm{Sym}^{\mu}(N_{X/Y}^*)).$$

In order to have an extension of $\mathbf{E}$ to a genuine analytic neighborhood of $X$ in $Y$, all these obstruction classes must vanish. In fact, if I understand correctly, you only provided the obstruction class for the extension of $\mathbf{E}$ to the first infinitesimal neighborhood $X \subset X_1$ of $X$ in $Y$.

Comment: Thank you, this is   exactly what I missed. You are right, the invariant  I have found is the first obstruction. The construction I used is more explicit then Griffiths', but it is probably still unpublishable.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I posted this https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.12461 .