# Higher obstructions to holomorphic tubular neighborhoods

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex manifold, let $S \subset X$ be a complex submanifold, and let $N_S := TX|_S / TS$ be the normal bundle.

**Definition.** A *tubular neighborhood* of $S$ in $X$ is a neighborhood $U$ of the zero section of $N_S$ together with a biholomorphism from $U$ to a neighborhood of $S$ in $X$ which is the identity on the zero section.

In contrast to the smooth category, there is a well-known obstruction to the existence of tubular neighborhoods:

**Proposition** (See e.g. [1, Proposition 2.5])***.*** *If $S$ has a tubular neighborhood in $X$, then the short exact sequence
$$
0 \to TS \to TX|_S \to N_S \to 0\tag{1}
$$
splits.*

As indicated in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/114416/134415) mathoverflow answer, this can be turned into a cohomological obstruction. There are many examples where this sequence does not split, such as any non-linear submanifold of $\mathbb{P}^n$ [1].

On the other hand, I am currently looking at a large family of pairs $(X, S)$ where (1) does split. I suspect that most of them still have no tubular neighborhood, but I am not sure how to proceed.

**Question.** *What are other obstructions to the existence of tubular neighborhoods beside the non-splitness of* (1)*?*

**References.**

[1] Morrow, J.; Rossi, H. Submanifolds of $\mathbb{P}^n$ with splitting normal bundle sequence are linear. Math. Ann. 234 (1978), no. 3, 253–261.

Comment: Two useful references: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0612449.pdf and the classic https://eudml.org/doc/160940